# How to use variable with THIS outside its scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While looping through a table column, the column index is stored in the variable columnIndex.
While in the loop the variable is defined but not outside of it.
How do I store the variable to use it also outside of the function?

```
    $('#excel_table td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
        var columnIndex = $(this).index();
        //SOME CODE...
        console.log(columnIndex);//RESULT = 1
    }); 
    console.log(columnIndex);//RESULT = Not defined
```

Comment: define it outside?

Comment: what is the purpose of 'columnIndex' ?

Comment: Assignment from a function to an outer var should be avoided for the same reason we avoid globals. The value, hence the code as a whole, is indeterminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var columnIndex = 0; // declare the variable

$('#excel_table td:nth-child('+ (1) + ')').each(function(){
    columnIndex = $(this).index();
    // ...
    console.log(columnIndex);
}); 

// use the variable outside of the inner scope
console.log(columnIndex);
```

Comment: you should consider the loop

Comment: Considering the loop doesn't change the fact that the variable has to be declared in the outer scope.

Comment: thanks @PeterMader. defining it outside the loop did the trick!

Comment: yep, it does actually. Because you're assigning always the last index value to columnIndex.

Comment: It is not part of the question how the variable should be used in the outer scope. When you use it in the loop as well, it will of course contain the value that was assigned in the last iteration. How can you tell that this wasn't intended by the OP?

Answer (score 4):

You should have the variable defined outside the loop, as array,

```
var columnIndex = [];

$('#excel_table td:nth-child('+ (1) + ')').each(function(i){
        columnIndex[i] = $(this).index();
        //SOME CODE...
        console.log(columnIndex);//RESULT = 1
    }); 
    console.log(columnIndex);//RESULT = Not defined
```

So outside it will show all the indexes in console.

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Define it outside the scope:

```
var columnIndex = "";
$('#excel_table td:nth-child('+ (1) + ')').each(function(){
    columnIndex = $(this).index();
    //SOME CODE...
    console.log(columnIndex);//RESULT = 1
}); 
console.log(columnIndex);//RESULT = Not defined
```

This will allow access outside of the each.

Comment: the `index` variable is coming from a loop `jQuery.prototype.each`, so, your `columnIndex` value will always be equal to the `index` value of the last iteration which makes your code equal to `var columnIndex = $('#excel_table td:nth-child('+ (1) + ')')[$('#excel_table td:nth-child('+ (1) + ')').length - 1]`

Comment: I know how a loop works. Not constructive in context of the question.

Comment: you're not assigning a `columnIndex` but a `lastColumnIndex` so your answers are wrong.

Comment: @Hitmands in the case of this example, the 1st column is always the same as the last.

Comment: `'#excel_table td:nth-child('+ (1) + ')'` will collect **all** the *first td* of the excel table, so, they can ben a lot. I think you should need to have a more deep look on everything.